# npm - `cd` fails when used a dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm using the postInstall script to run `cd node_modules/<package-name> && ...`. This works fine when running by itself. However when I use the package as a dependency it fails to find `<dependant-package>/node_modules/<package>/node_modules` which seems to be understandable as dependencies for `<package>` are in `<dependent-package>/node_modules`. I'm using a forked project where this script appears to work but it fails in my fork. I'm wondering if there's an easy fix for this. I'm using a namespace and wonder if that changes anything...

Comment: How is this script being run? Is it a bash script? We need more details.

Comment: Minor edit to try to clarify but its is literally `"scripts": {"postInstall" : "cd node_modules/<package-name> && ...}"`

Comment: Okay so npm is running it. First use ls to figure out where your at then work from there. Also check ownership of dir your trying to cd to. What errors are you getting also?

Comment: Everything is owned by my user. I dont see how ls would help. I've modified the script to `pwd && cd node_modules/<package-name> && ...` and it is at `<dependent-package>/node_modules/<package>`

Comment: ls would let you know which dir npm is starting from. dir scope can get weird with node and npm.

Comment: `pwd` would be a more logical choice....?

Comment: pwd learned something new haha. Okay what version of npm are you running? Remember new versions of npm will install duplicates in the root of node_modules not in the sub modules node_modules dir

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the soloution to this is to force NPM to install the dependency twice by using the npm version in one package.json and the github url in the other.